# Creating weight logic in django based off past 7 days

Tags: python, django

I currently have a `Restaurant` model with associated models `Review` and `Comment`. Users can comment and review a restaurant.

I'm trying to create weight logic in Django in which I display the top three restaurants with the largest weight.

The current logic looks like this:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()
top_3 = restaurants.annotate(weight=(Count('review')) + F('views') + (Count('comment'))).order_by('-weight')
```

How can I update this logic so that only the reviews and comments for the past 7 days are factored into the weight?

**Edit**
The Review and Comment models both have a field for tracking when the object was created: 
`pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)`

Comment: What is `views` field?

Comment: Good question. It's a field within the Restaurant model. Basically an integer with the total number of views that a restaurant has received. This actually doesn't have to factor in the past 7 days. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
import datetime

from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils import timezone    

week_ago = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
top_3 = Restaurant.objects.filter(
    Q(review__isnull=True) | Q(review__pub_date__gt=week_ago),
    Q(comment__isnull=True) | Q(comment__pub_date__gt=week_ago),
).annotate(weight=...).order_by('-weight')[:3]
```

`review__isnull=True` and `comment__isnull=True` are to not filter out `restaurants` that are without `reviews` and `comments`. If you don't care about those `restaurants`, you can use this filter:

```
filter(review__pub_date__gt=week_ago, comment__pub_date__gt=week_ago)
```

Docs

- [`filter()` and `exclude()` with annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude)
- [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
- [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: He wants to calculate for the past 7 days, not today only. So I guess it should be: `pub_date__gt=today - timedelta(days=7)`

Comment: Only thing I had to fix was: `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` `week_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)`

Comment: Looking back at this query, wouldn't this filter out Restaurants with Reviews, but that haven't been reviewed in the past week?